# SQL query for getting only the latest data

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to make a SQL query where I am only able to see my latest shipments. Currently I get the following result.

```
item    date        licence plate number
1       13.5.2016   abc-123
2       13.5.2016   abc-123
3       10.5.2016   xyz-567
1       20.4.2016   abc-123
2       20.4.2016   abc-123
6       10.5.2016   xyz-567
```

However I would like to only get the latest shipments based on the licence plate number. The wanted output would look like

```
item    date        licence plate number
1       13.5.2016   abc-123
2       13.5.2016   abc-123
3       10.5.2016   xyz-567
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Define "latest", then we can help you. What makes item 3 included, but item 6 excluded?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Column date's data type?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT item, MAX("date") AS "date"
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY item
) AS t2 ON t1.item = t2.item AND t1."date" = t2."date"
```

The query uses a derived table which selects the latest date per `item`. Using this derived table we can select the record that corresponds to this date.

Answer (score 1):

The following is standard SQL supported by a wide range of DBMS:

```
select item, date, licence_plate_number
from (
    select item, date, licence_plate_number, 
           row_number() over (partition by licence_plate_number order by date desc as rn)
    from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by item;
```

Using a window function is typically faster than a self join with an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT TOP 10 --change 10 to any desired number to be viewed 
*
FROM YourDatabaseName 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: Not what OP is asking for. (And product specific answer to a question with no dbms tagged.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first find our the max date of each plate number then join the tables.

You can use below query.

```
select t2."item",t1."date",t1."licence plate number" from (
(select max("date") as date, "licence plate number" from Table_1 group by 
"licence plate number")) t1
 left join Table_1 t2 
on (t1."date" =  t2."date" and t1."licence plate number" =  t2."licence plate number")
```

The output of this query will be.

```
1      2016-05-13      abc-123
2      2016-05-13      abc-123
3      2016-05-10      xyz-567
6      2016-05-10      xyz-567
```

Comment: Note that square brackets for delimited identifiers is product specific, and the question has no dbms tagged. ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"item"`. (MS SQL Server actually supports both versions.)